Is it possible to use terraform with AWS Academy?
I've been trying to use terraform with AWS Academy account for a while, but I can't create any resource because says that I have access denied cause of the role. But the problem is that I can create the resources directly using aws-cli, but with terraform I cannot.
There are some limitations with AWS Academy account like, I cannot assume any role for example, I tried to use de assume_role but this is really forbidden on my student user.
I am using this user based configuration:
provider "aws" {

region = var.region

access_key = var.access_key

secret_key = var.secret_access_key

token = var.session_token

}

Every time that I login on aws-academy I get those keys and put on my .aws files.
I tried a lot of configurations to try to solve the problem and create those resources, like
provider "aws" {
  region                   = var.region
  shared_config_files      = ["~/.aws/config"]
  shared_credentials_files = ["~/.aws/credentials"]
}

I change my credentials file as well adding some specific profiles:
.aws/config
[default]
region=us-east-1
output=json

.aws/credentials
[default]
aws_access_key_id=****
aws_secret_access_key=***
aws_session_token=*****

Every time that I run terraform apply returns those errors when creating a simple S3 Bucket:
Error: creating Amazon S3 (Simple Storage) Bucket (new bucket): AccessDenied: Access Denied

Again I can create those resources using aws-cli and directly from AWS Console, I even can create them using AWS Cloud Formation (YAML)


UPDATE: I was capable of doing by using terraform HCP and GitHub actions following this doc:
https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/automation/github-actions

You can't create role in AWS Academy; you should use labsrole that is pre-created for you.
Welcome to Stack Overflow. Are you student or professor? If student - ask your professor. If professor - ask the question in the forum. There are a number of educators that use terraform for the classes. The question for SO or - better - re:Post would be "Is it possible to run Terraform scripts with preexisting role?" And you may already know the answer to that question

So I think I cannot use it! thanks S2
